# I need help with the adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I need help with this exercise. I can't see my mistake. Really I'm so sad because I tried during hours.

Let $V=P_1(\mathbb{R})$ (the space of polynomials with degree equal to one) and $\left\langle f,g \right\rangle=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)g(x) \, dx$ inner product in $V$ and $T:V\rightarrow V$ such that $T(f)=f'+3f$.

Get $T^{*}$ (the adjoint operator) and proof that $\left\langle T(a),b \right\rangle=\left\langle a,T^{*}(b) \right\rangle$ with $a=4-2x$ and $b=x+10$

My solution:

Let $\left\{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}} \, x  \right\}$ be a orthonormal basis of $V$. (it is, with the inner product defined).

Now,

$T\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=0+\displaystyle\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}=3\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+0\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}} \, x$

$T\left( \sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}} \, x\right)=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}}+3\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}} \, x=\sqrt{3}\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+3\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{3}{2}} \, x$. Then, the matrix associated with the transformation is 
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
3 & \sqrt{3} \\
0 & 3 \\
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

Then, the matrix of the adjoint operator $T^{*}$ is 
\begin{equation}
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
3 & 0 \\
\sqrt{3} & 3 \\
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

My problem is here. How can I get the correspondence rule of $T^{*}$? I did but, I thought that this is wrong. My result is $T^{*}(b+ax)=3b+(\sqrt{3}b+3a)x$